# Get database field for custom select form field in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a form that works. I created a new form element that is a multi-select field for date. It combines day, month, and year into one form element like so:

Form Item:

```
$this->addElement('date', 'new_date', array(
    'label'         => 'Expires as New on?'
));
```

Form Element:

```
<?php

require_once 'Zend/Form/Element/Multi.php';

class Zend_Form_Element_Date extends Zend_Form_Element_Multi
{
    public $helper = 'formDate';
    protected $_registerInArrayValidator = false;

    private $data;

    public function isValid ($data) {
        $this->data=$data;
        return true;
    }

    public function getValue () {
         return $this->data[2].'-'.$this->data[0].'-'.$this->data[1];
    }
}
```

Helper Element:

```
<?php

require_once 'Zend/View/Helper/FormElement.php';

class Zend_View_Helper_FormDate extends Zend_View_Helper_FormElement
{

    public function formDate($name, $value = null, $attribs = null,
        $options = null, $listsep = "<br />\n")
    {


        $info = $this->_getInfo($name, $value, $attribs, $options, $listsep);
        extract($info); // name, id, value, attribs, options, listsep, disable


        // force $value to array so we can compare multiple values
        // to multiple options.

        $value = array_map('strval', (array) $value);
        //Zend_Debug::dump($value);
        $olddata = explode("-",$value[0]);  
        //Zend_Debug::dump($olddata);   

        // check if element may have multiple values
        $multiple = '';

        if (substr($name, -2) == '[]') {
            // multiple implied by the name
            $multiple = ' multiple="multiple"';
        }

        if (isset($attribs['multiple'])) {
            // Attribute set
            if ($attribs['multiple']) {
                // True attribute; set multiple attribute
                $multiple = ' multiple="multiple"';

                // Make sure name indicates multiple values are allowed
                if (!empty($multiple) && (substr($name, -2) != '[]')) {
                    $name .= '[]';
                }
            } else {
                // False attribute; ensure attribute not set
                $multiple = '';
            }
            unset($attribs['multiple']);
        } 

        // now start building the XHTML.
        $disabled = '';
        if (true === $disable) {
            $disabled = ' disabled="disabled"';
        }

        // Build the surrounding select element first.
        $xhtml = '<select'
                . ' name="' . $this->view->escape($name) . '[]"'
                . ' id="' . $this->view->escape($id) . '"'
                . $multiple
                . $disabled
                . $this->_htmlAttribs($attribs)
                . ">\n    ";

        // build the list of options

        // month
        $month = array();

        $month[] = $this->_build('MM', 'MM');

        for($i = 1; $i<= 12; $i++){
            $m = date("M", mktime(0,0,0,$i));
            $month[] = $this->_build($i<10?'0'.$i:$i, $m, $olddata[1]);
        }

        $day = array();

        $day[] = $this->_build('DD', 'DD');
        for($i = 1; $i<=31; $i++){
            $day[] = $this->_build($i<10?'0'.$i:$i, $i<10?'0'.$i:$i, $olddata[2]);
        }

        $year = array();

        $year[] = $this->_build('YYYY','YYYY');

        for($i = (int)date("Y"); $i < (int)date("Y")+11; $i++){
            $year[] = $this->_build($i, $i, $olddata[0]);
        }

        // add the options to the xhtml and close the select
        $month = $xhtml.implode("\n    ", $month) . "\n</select>";
        $day = $xhtml.implode("\n    ", $day) . "\n</select>";
        $year = $xhtml.implode("\n    ", $year) . "\n</select>";

        return $month.$day.$year;
    }

    protected function _build($value, $label, $selected)
    {

        $opt = '<option'
             . ' value="' . $this->view->escape($value) . '"'
             . ' label="' . $this->view->escape($label) . '"';

       if ($value == $selected) {
            $opt .= ' selected="selected"';
        }

        $opt .= '>' . $this->view->escape($label). "</option>";

        return $opt;
    }

}
```

I have been able to save the data from this form element into the database. Yet when I attempt to load the form, all form elements receive the database values except my custom form element. Can anyone direct me to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think you're missing a setValue method - see [this tutorial](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/217-Creating-composite-elements.html) on composite elements by the Zend Framework lead.

Comment: Thanks, that is a great tutorial and exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, in your `Zend_View_Helper_FormDate::_build($value, $label, $selected)` you have 3rd param that is used to add `selected="selected"` to your HTML but inside  your `formDate` method your only passing the first 2 arguments ie. `$this->_build('MM', 'MM');`

You will have to pass the value in the 3rd param. Also, -10 pts for using `Zend` namespace for custom elements. That's a big no-no. :P

**EDIT**

Replace In Helper:

```
$value = array_map('strval', (array) $value);
//Zend_Debug::dump($value);
$olddata = explode("-",$value[0]);  
//Zend_Debug::dump($olddata);
```

With:

```
if ( !empty($value)) {
    $value = array_map('strval', (array) $value);
    $olddata = explode("-",$value[0]);
} else {
    $olddata = array('','','');
}
```

Then

```
protected function _build($value, $label, $selected)
```

With:

```
protected function _build($value, $label, $selected = null)
```

Add to your custom element:

```
public function setValue($value)
{
    /** Assuming format Y-m-d and need m-d-Y**/
    list($year,$month,$day) = explode('-', $value);
    $this->data = array($month,$day,$year);
    // Almost forgot
    return $this;
}
```

Note: Was only poking fun at you about the Zend namespace.

Comment: Thank so much for your unhelpful advice. You make assumptions and then assume you have an answer. This should just be a comment. For starters you didn't even read the code. The piece of code where you are suggesting the 3rd param is for the title of the select field which would never be selected. That is why the 3rd param is in the for loop. As for being in Zend namespace I am in development, once it works it will move out of there, thanks for asking.

Comment: my apologies, here let me edit my answer and give you a solution.